# How can I implement an splitpane in ZedGraph?

Tags: zedgraph

On my Masterpane I have 2 panes. Is there a way to change the height of the panes with the mouse (like a sashpane or splitpane?)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this once. It is possible to do it only with one ZG control, but it's hard.

The easiest way is to create your own control with splitpane containing two ZG controls inside.